# Grails controller unit testing MethodSelectionException

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a unit testing class that is throwing this strange exception...I don't have idea what it means...can someone help me?

this is the class:

```
@TestFor(ApplicationController)
@TestMixin(MvcUnitTestCase)
class ApplicationControllerTests{

def init(){
    super.init(ApplicationController)
}

void testCheckOk() {
   def service = mockFor(ApplicationService)
   def myModel = new MyModel();
   service.demand.getModel {
       return myModel 
   }
   controller.service = service.createMock()
   def model = controller.index()

   assertEquals myModel, model.myModel
   assertEquals HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, response.status
}
```

this is the exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
public grails.test.MvcUnitTestCase#<init>(java.lang.String)
public grails.test.MvcUnitTestCase#<init>(java.lang.Class)
```

Comment: `MvcUnitTestCase` has two constructors one that takes a String and one that takes a Class.  I'm assuming that it is something to do with that but I'm not sure why it would be happening.  Simply having a test case which uses `MvcUnitTestCase` as a mixin causes this problem.

Comment: I think the problem may be that you're mixing in two things by including `@TestMixin(MvcUnitTestCase)`. You shouldn't need to do that as you've already got `@TestFor(ApplicationController)` which will mix in the appropriate things automatically.